# LocusZoom standalone change x-axis and use the plots in a script

Tags: r, integration

I am using the standalone LocusZoom software,but I am having two problems:

I have to create a plot showing only position on the x-axis (not showing the genes). If I just use showGenes=FALSE with nothing else the genes still appear, but if I use rfrows=0 then the genes are not shown, but the problem is that also the x-axis label with the positions disappears. Is there a way to only show the position label? It looks like the only way to do this is to modify the original script...

Is there a way to use several plots created using LocusZoom in an R script to position many plots into one unique figure? (output is a pdf for now) There is an option listed in the LocusZoom webpage (http://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/LocusZoom_Standalone) called "prelude" but I cannot get more info on how to use it.

If you have any suggestions for either of these two issues it would be very helpful! Thanks!!